# Зависание NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

В приложении есть NavigationDrawer. Нажатие на пункт меню открывает соответствующий ему фрагмент. Один из фрагментов загружается дольше остальных. Пока он загружается, шторка NavigationDrawer зависает до тех пор, пока данные не загрузятся во фрагмент. Зависание длится недолго, но для глаза неприятно. Как можно визуально улучшить данный процесс?

**UPD:** подойдет вариант, когда одновременно закрывается шторка и загружается фрагмент, т.к. время, требуемое для загрузки фрагмента и время, требуемое для закрытия шторки, примерно одинаковое. Но из-за поверхностных знаний Java не представляю, как правильно это сделать

**UPD[2]:**

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_fridge:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1, tag_1);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_what_to_cook:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2, tag_2);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_recipes:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3, tag_3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: добавьте код обработки выбора пункта меню

Comment: Перестать грузить UI тред.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja можно подробнее?

Comment: @mtrfnv, что выполняете в этом фрагменте?Скорей всего выполняете что то тяжелое на UI потоке.

Comment: Скорее всего можно просто сначала вызвать метод закрытия меню и только потом фрагмент добавлять

Comment: Без кода никаких подробностей быть не может.

Comment: @UjinUkr загрузка данных из БД в ListView

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja добавил код

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych добавил код

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить задержку перед загрузкой фрагмента, чтобы дать NavigationDrawer полностью закрыться. Класс Handler даёт возможность реализовать отложенное по времени выполнение кода:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    switch (id) {
                       case R.id.nav_fridge:
                          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, 
                          fragment1, tag_1);
                       break;
                       case R.id.nav_what_to_cook:
                          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, 
                          fragment2, tag_2);
                       break;
                       case R.id.nav_recipes:
                          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, 
                          fragment3, tag_3);
                       break;
                       default:
                       break;
                   }
                 fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }, 250); //где 250 это время задержки в миллисекундах
            return true;
```

Поэкспериментируйте с временем задержки.